# Is it possible to remove the requirement for Android permission requests for internally distributed apps?

Tags: android-permissions

We have an app distributed **only internally**.  It is **never** published in any store.  Is there a way to grant the app all the permissions by default so that there will be no need to request any permissions? Or, is there a way to configure an Android device to grant an app all the permissions in advance to avoid runtime permission requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the app target API 22 or lower.

Comment: Thank you for the tip.  The app currently targets API 27.  Not sure what other changes lowering to 22 would cause.  I will accept this answer if I there no others without the need to change the target.